# Firewall log MAC address

Tags: firewall

I'm checking my linux server's firewall and I'm seeing

"....IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:26:a9:7b:c9:30:00:17:0f:ac:6a:80:08:00"...

As far as I know MAC addresses have 12 Characters. Why are there 28 characters in front of MAC=?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

6 bytes destination MAC, 6 bytes source MAC, 2 bytes frame type.

Comment: Thanks, could you please break up each part and tell me what the frame type is? I just can't work out how 28 characters represent 3 bytes.

Comment: `00:26:a9:7b:c9:30` - Destination MAC, `00:17:0f:ac:6a:80` - Source MAC, `08:00` - Frame type (See http://www.iana.org/assignments/ethernet-numbers - your frame type is 0x0800 aka IPv4)